# ModelSim for XILINX 12.1 design suite

Tags: fpga

I've downloaded XILINX ISE 12.1 but I am facing problems with Modelsim. I've download it as well but there's no set up file in the Modelsim folder. How I get this installed? Do I have to install something else first. Generally speaking if someone knows how to install Modelsim for 12.1 suite please let me know.

Comment: I don't think ISE includes Modelsim any more.  There is the ISE simulator

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the ModelSim package is not correct. Make sure you download it from ModelSim Website (http://model.com/). After registration, it gives you a temp FTP login name and password. If you select the correct version, it contains the setup exe file.